# Is it possible to have user friendly IP addresses on local network machines?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-access

I have a few machines on my home network that I ssh into. Windows, Mac, and Linux.

instead of ssh name@123.0.0.1 every time I want to login to one of them it would be nice to set the IP as something user friendly. Possibly even the remote computers hostname?

Say my name is Matt and I want to login to my machine that has a hostname of thinkpad.

Could I ssh matt@thinkpad to login somehow?

Comment: [Hostnames for Local Application Servers](https://commotionwireless.net/docs/guides-howtos/local-applications/hostnames.html)

Comment: This looks great! I’ll read into it and hopefully solved what I’m looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your remote host using the hostname instead of ip, you need update /etc/hosts

sudo nano /etc/hosts
Add the details of your server

123.0.0.1 thinkpad

Comment: So I place host name next to what the local ip is?

Comment: @ChrisThomas IP1 hostname1
IP2 hostname2

Comment: For  hosts file format, read the `hosts(5)` manpage.